# Get A Certain Value In NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Let's say the name of dictionary is `nameOfDictionary` and the key name is `string`.

I was trying to get the value of the dictionary by using:

```
[nameOfDictionary objectForKey:@"string"];
```

However, I was getting the one at the bottom. Is there anyway I can get the `222` or `sample` alone?

```
{
   222 = "sample";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the one at the bottom"? I'm having trouble understanding your question here.

Comment: can't understand your question.

Comment: Oh what I mean is when I run this [nameOfDictionary objectForKey:@"string"]; I was getting the one at the bottom, I like to get 222 or sample alone instead.

Comment: can u tell me where u are setting the object for the key?? can u show the code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the object under the "string" key is also a dictionary. So you can do this to get the key and value of that dictionary separately.

`NSDictionary *nameOfDictionary = @{@"string":@{@"222":@"Sample"}};
    NSDictionary *dict = nameOfDictionary[@"string"];
    for (NSString *key in [dict keyEnumerator]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, dict[key]);
    }`

`key` will contain 222 and `dict[key]` will contain sample

Comment: Ah! You understand! I was about to paste the code but nevermind, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try **`allKeys`** function will return all keys,

```
for( NSString *aKey in [dictionary allKeys])
{
    NSLog(@"Do something with the key here:%@",aKey );
}
```